# Printing columns with specific pattern and all values

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed

I have a file like this:

```
     OV2  OVI  1VI  OV3  3VI  
er    23   23   23   23   23  
tr    24   24   24   24   24
```

I want to print the 1st column along with any columns whose name contains `VI` (I don't know which columns will contain the string beforehand). In the example above, the output should be like this:

```
     OVI  1VI  3VI  
er    23   23   23     
tr    24   24   24
```

all the columns should be tab delimited.

Comment: Will you know which columns have `VI` or does the solution need to find them?

Comment: i need to print the column cntains VI

Comment: Yes, but do you know it will be the 2nd, 3d and last column? Or do our solutions need to find that out?

Comment: actually i have many columns containing VI.

Comment: Wait, the first column doesn't have a header? Please always show representative examples. It is very tiring when you change the input data like this.

Comment: sorry for the edits. this is the final data now

Comment: How are the columns defined? Are they space-separated or tab-separated? Is there an extra tab in the first line for the missing field?

Comment: the columns are tab seperated. for the fisrt column head you can put any value, no problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
perl -lane '$,="\t";
   $. == 1 and @A = grep $F[$_] =~ /VI/, 0..$#F;
   print @F[0,@A];
' yourfile
```

### Results

```
ID      OVI     1VI     3VI
er      23      23      23
tr      24      24      24
```

### Working

- From the first line, `$. == 1` extract the indices of the fields that contain the string `VI`.
- Armed with these list of indices now in array `@A`, we just plain go ahead and slice out the 1st field + the fields listed in the `@A` array from the the `@F` array. The `OFS=$,` has been set to a `TAB`. YMMV.

---

### awk

```
awk -v OFS="\t" '
   NR==1{
      for ( i=2; i<=NF; i++ )
         if ( $i ~ /VI/ )
            str = str OFS i
      N = split(str, A, OFS)
   }{
      s = $1
      for ( i=2; i<=N; i++ )
         s = s OFS $(A[i])
      $0 = s
   }1
' yourfile
```

---

### SED

```
sed -e '
   # TAB->spc, multiple spc -> single spc, trim leading/trailing spc
   y/ / /;s/[ ]\{2,\}/ /g;s/^[ ][ ]*//;s/[ ][ ]*$//

   # only for first line, remove the first field and store remaining in hold area
   1{
      h
         s/[ ]/\
/
         s/.*\n//
      x
   }

   # append hold area (which now has 2nd...last fields
   # data of the first record) to the present line and
   # place a marker at the end of the first field
   G
   s/[^ ][^ ]*[ ]/&\
/

   # setup a do-while loop which progressively either keeps VI data or trims it
   :loop
      #  1     2                      3
      s/\(\n\)\([^ ][^ ]*\)[ ]\{0,1\}\(.*\n\)[^ ]*VI[^ ]*[ ]\{0,1\}/ \2\1\3/;tloop
      s/\(\n\)[^ ][^ ]*[ ]\{0,1\}\(.*\n\)[^ ][^ ]*[ ]\{0,1\}/\1\2/
   /\n\n$/!bloop
   # loop ends when the two \ns collide at the end of line

   # remove the two \ns and what remains is what you wanted
   s///

' yourfile
```

Comment: thanks. it workes. but I am looking for awk solution. because I am used to with perl

Comment: @MasumBillah I've added a bare-bones `awk` code.

Answer (score 2):

***awk*** solution:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS="[\t ]+"; OFS="\t"}NR==1{for(i=2;i<=NF;i++)
    {if($i~/VI/) a[i]; }}{r=$1; for(i in a) r=r OFS $i; print l}' file
```

The output:

```
    OVI 1VI 3VI
er  23  23  23
tr  24  24  24
```

---

- `FS="[\t ]+"` - input field separator
- `OFS="\t"` - output field separator
- `NR==1` - for the first *header* line
- `if($i~/VI/) a[i]` - capturing field number if it matches `VI`
- `r=$1; for(i in a) r=r OFS $i; print r` - iterating through needed field numbers and printing their respective values

---

If you encountering an order breaking use the following with `asorti()` function (to sort array by indices):

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS="[\t ]+"; OFS="\t"}NR==1{for(i=2;i<=NF;i++)
    {if($i~/VI/) a[i]; }}{r=$1; asorti(a,b); for(i in b) {r=r OFS $(b[i])} print r}' file
```

Comment: Sorry, this is not working as per my requirement. because, I want the first column remain as column 1 then other columns whose column head contains VI and it should be tab delimited. but as per your command the values are in same column and the first column goes to the last line

Comment: @MasumBillah then please edit your question and make that requirement clear. You didn't mention it anywhere.

Comment: @MasumBillah, that's because you are playing with requirements "on the fly" - that's not good

Comment: @MasumBillah, see the final update

Comment: i checked, it is working but the first column is still in the last column, but i thibk it is ok now

Comment: @MasumBillah, *the first column is still in the last column* - sounds fantastically )

Comment: i mean the order changes.

Comment: @MasumBillah, isn't the output looks like that that you your question?

Comment: no, it differs in the orders

Comment: interesting, do all other people see that difference? I would ask them

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest `awk` arrays are `associative` hence `for(i in a)` would return the elements not necessarily in the sorted order. That's what is causing the OP to see the mismatch in the field printing order.

Comment: @RakeshSharma, perhaps he works with more extended input and gets a broken order. I've added additional `asorti()` approach

Answer (score 1):

Python script solution. Operates on the basis of parsing first line, and building up a list of columns. Those columns that don't have VI in them, are set to None. All other lines are split into words and joined into pairs with column list items for comparison. If corresponding column item is None, that word from the current line won't be printed. Otherwise, things that are not None are printed

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import sys

with open(sys.argv[1]) as fd:
    indexes = []
    for index,line in enumerate(fd):
        if index == 0:
            columns = line.strip().split()
            for i,col in enumerate(columns):
                if 'VI' in col or i == 0:
                    indexes.append(col)
                else:
                    indexes.append(None)
            for x in indexes:
                if x:
                    print(x,end=" ")
            print("")
            continue
        for j in zip(line.strip().split(),indexes):
            if j[1]:
                print(j[0],end=" ")
        print("")
```

Note: replace `end=" "` with `end="\t"` to have tab-delimited output

Test run:

```
$ ./get_colums.py input.txt                                                                                              
ID  OVI 1VI 3VI 
er  23  23  23  
tr  24  24  24
```